# What does "resolute detail" mean?

Tags: meaning

What does "resolute detail" mean? The context is this:

> Aristotle caught again the thread of scientific development in the
>   pre-Socratic Greeks, carried on Plato's work with more resolute detail.

How can a detail become "resolute"?

Comment: Ploto? Maybe Plato? No?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Plato. Sorry for my typo.

Answer (score 1):

It's not about *a* detail. *Detail* here is used generically.

What "resolute detail" actually means here is that in the works of Aristotle, the development of the sciences was more detailed than ever before; and the word *resolute* here signifies, in this metaphorical manner, that Aristotle's new approach to the development of the sciences is "[determined and unwavering](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/resolute)."